# Method "Get" with signature "ss" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" doesn't exist

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, dbus, bluez

I am developing bluez and dbus software in python for automated testing purposes. Recently one of my methods: isconnected(), which checks the property "Connected" of all managed objects, has been throwing errors. Pasting the error below:

```
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 401, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 269, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 124, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 93, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 670, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 266, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 65, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 227, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 160, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "./app.py", line 46, in disconnectall
    bluez.disconnectall()
  File "./bluez.py", line 303, in disconnectall
    if isconnected(bdaddr):
  File "./bluez.py", line 318, in isconnected
    isconnected = getinterface.Get(bluetooth_constants.DEVICE_INTERFACE, connected)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 72, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 141, in __call__
    return self._connection.call_blocking(self._named_service,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
    reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownObject: Method "Get" with signature "ss" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" doesn't exist
```

Here is isconnected():

```
def isconnected (bdaddr):
    connected = 'Connected'
    device_path = bluetooth_utils.device_address_to_path(bdaddr, mybus.adapter_path_1)
    device_proxy = mybus.bus.get_object(bluetooth_constants.BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME,device_path)
    getinterface  = dbus.Interface(device_proxy, bluetooth_constants.DBUS_PROPERTIES)
    isconnected = getinterface.Get(bluetooth_constants.DEVICE_INTERFACE, connected)
    return isconnected
```

Any ideas on what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

That just means you are calling a methods on an object that is currently not on the dbus. In other words you need to run a discovery first...

Comment: That would have been a nice solution. However, this is of course after I have scanned. I just reproduced the problem now, after having scanned and connected to a device I attempted to find the BTprofiles of the device, so I looked at connected devices on the bus and ran isconnected => same error. Perhaps something to do with devices being removed from bus during the methodcall? Using dbus-monitor --system I can see that interfaces are removed very rapidly after finishing scanning, is this something I can change?

Comment: I have seen devices disappear rapidly after scanning as well. In particular devices with random addresses. Upgrading to at least 5.64 solved the issue for me. Alternatively, try keeping discovery on when connecting....

Comment: @JakobWirén was this ever fixed? I'm getting the same error, but while trying to use bluetooth. [Bluetooth headset keeps connecting and disconnecting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1490314/bluetooth-headset-keeps-connecting-and-disconnecting)